# Is it possible to use an ordered Collector with a parallel stream?

Tags: java, parallel-processing, java-8, java-stream

When computing Cartesian Products using streams, I can produce them in parallel, and consume them in order, which the following code demonstrates:

```
int min = 0;
int max = 9;
Supplier<IntStream> supplier = () -> IntStream.rangeClosed(min, max).parallel();
supplier.get()
        .flatMap(a -> supplier.get().map(b -> a * b))
        .forEachOrdered(System.out::println);
```

This will print everything perfectly in order, now consider the following code where I want to add it to a list, while preserving the order.

```
int min = 0;
int max = 9;
Supplier<IntStream> supplier = () -> IntStream.rangeClosed(min, max).parallel();
List<Integer> list = supplier.get()
        .flatMap(a -> supplier.get().map(b -> a * b))
        .boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
list.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Now it does not print in order!
This is understandable given that I nowhere demand that the order should be preserved.

Now the question: Is there a way to `collect()` or is there a `Collector` that preserves order?

Comment: And why not just create the list beforehand and `.forEachOrdered(i -> list.add(i))`?

Comment: @fge That defeats some purpose of the `Collector`, I would not do that for a normal sequential collector either.

Comment: That is giving me output in order only :-/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I executed your code, I got the outputs in order. In fact got the same output for both the code. It seems like the `Collector` returned from `Collectors.toList` is already ordered, as being depicted by following code:

```
Collector collector = Collectors.toList();
System.out.print(collector.characteristics());
```

it prints:

```
[IDENTITY_FINISH]
```

Since there is no `UNORDERED` characteristics set for the collector, it will process the elements in order only, and which is what the behaviour I'm seeing.

In fact this is clearly mentioned in the docs of [`Collectors.toList()`](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toList--):

> **Returns:**
>   a `Collector` which collects all the input elements into a `List`, in encounter order

Comment: You are correct, I must have misread it then a whle ago, because I tested again and it is executing in order. And definately a +1 for the confirmation there.